# Parse string by space, Place each item into linked list. NO ARRAYS

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm currently working with linked lists. My assignment is asking me to make use of them in order to create a reverse polish calculator. I am having trouble understanding how to place each part of the string into the stack. My code currently looks like this

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList data = new LinkedList();
            string UserData = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a calculation in polish notation.");
            data.Parse(UserData);

        }
```

here i am simply accessing the parse method within the "LinkedList" class that receives the string "UserData". From there I'd like to start reading through the string and placing each part into the stack. I am not clear on how I can achieve that without arrays.

 Here is my parse method:

```
public void Parse(string Input)
        {
            int data;  
            if(Input!=null)
            {

            }

        }
```

As you can see I have nothing in it. In my head I'm thinking I should parse the string, then place each item in the stack but I'm more than likely wrong. Here is the entire LinkedList Class just in case:

```
public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node FrontHead;

        public void printNodes()
        {
            Node Current = FrontHead;
            while (Current != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Current.data);
                Current = Current.next;
            }
        }
        public void Parse(string Input)
        {
            int data;  
            if(Input!=null)
            {


            }

        }              
        public void Add(Object data)
        {
            Node NextToadd = new Node();
            NextToadd.data = data;
            NextToadd.next = FrontHead;
            FrontHead = NextToadd;
        }
        public void last(Object data)
        {
            if (FrontHead == null)
            {
                FrontHead = new Node();
                FrontHead.data = data;
                FrontHead.next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Node New = new Node();
                New.data = data;

                Node Crt = FrontHead;
                while (Crt.next != null)
                {
                    Crt = Crt.next;
                }
                Crt.next = New;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Node Class:

```
 public class Node
    {
        public Object data;
        public Node next;              
    }
```

a sample run would look like this:
input:
1 2 + =
output:
3

Comment: Why would you like to use a custom linked list? You have the class List<> in c#, which is exactly that, is managed and have already any add/remove/edit/search functions. Ex: List<MyObjectType> mylist = new List<MyObjectType>(); MyObjectType obj = new MyObjectType(); obj.field = "foo"; mylist.add(obj).

Comment: Carles, as he already stated this is for an assignment that he is struggling with. I think he may be limited by the assignment specification. Also with that said it's a good assignment to help you understand what's happening with the built in lists by implementing methods such as pop, push, insert etc. Especially with the reverse polish notation which will require methods to check if the character is an operation, pop the first two numbers, perform that operation, push the answer back to the list etc

Comment: Might be out of scope for the assignment but normally you would place the Parse (+ Calculator) code in a different class. It does simplify things.

Comment: Also, did your class mention LIFO and FIFO queues?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes they were.

Comment: Then create a Parser (method)  that uses String.Split() , a LIFO (Stack) class based on a Linked List and a calculator using the two.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
public void Parse(string Input)
{
    if(Input!=null)
    {
       foreach (string s in Input.Split(' '))
       {
           Add(s);
       }
    }
}
```

But technically speaking, Split returns an array. So it depends what you mean by "NO ARRAYS", as i'm assuming that means the linked list is not an array, but arrays can be used elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate each sub-string of given string in Parse method. and call last(Name as per your code) method to add each substring to your list

```
public void Parse(string Input)
{
        int data;  
        if(Input!=null)
        {
            foreach(string subString in Input.Split(' '))
            {
               //call last method
                last(subString);
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: you've made a small spelling mistake :)

Comment: Also it's Split() not split()

Comment: Why `last()` instead of `Add()` ?

Comment: `last()` method actually performing add operation as you can observes op's code carefully.

Comment: But at the other end.